# How to add two Field Instances in a Django Model into a variable?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Good day! I'm trying to understand if there is a proper way of adding **name_first** & **name_last** Fields in the **Customer** Model into **name_full** Field. The **name_full** Field will be used as ftring renurn value for the Model. Relation with the **Order** Model via *Foreign Key*.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name_first = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    name_last = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    # name_full = ... name_first+name_last

def __str__(self):
    return self.name_full
```

I've tried looking for similar question and there is a slight chance of not knowing how to ask a proper question)
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and use [**`Concat`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#concat) to concatenate the values:

```
from django.db.models import CharField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

Customer.objects.annotate(
    full_name=Concat(
        'name_first', Value(' '), 'name_last',
        output_field=CharField()
    )
).filter(
    full_name='Serhii Didukh'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want `name_full` field to be just another model field, you can add it as such, and override `save()` method in order to set it to the concat of `name_first` and `name_last` everytime the instance is saved:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name_first = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    name_last = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)
    name_full = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=False, blank=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name_full

def save(self)
    self.name_full = "{} {}".format(self.name_first, self.name_last)

    super().save()
```

Comment: One of the main problems is that the Django ORM does not run `.save()` each time. A simple example is `Customer.objects.filter(first_name='Jnoh').update(first_name='John')`. We here for example fix a typo, but the `.save()` function will not run due to a bulk update.